# Cannot import name 'GeoText' from the geotext Python package

Tags: python, import, importerror, geotext

I have installed the geotext module from pip.

However this line:

```
from geotext import GeoText
```

produces this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoText'
```

The module structure is as follows:
[image: geotext module contents]
where there is no sub directory but directly the geotext python file containing the GeoText class:
[image: GeoText class]
The correct syntax of "from module import Class" is used in the `__init__.py` file too.

```
from geotext import GeoText
```

Could anyone help me interpret as to why the error could be generated in such a scenario where there seems to be no circular imports?

Answer (score 0):

The import statement from the **init** file needs to be removed. This corrects the circular import scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Installing geotext like so fixed it for me:

```
python3 -m pip install geotext
```